# How to get Collection view Dynamic Row count?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

**I'm collecting data from an API**

sample API - This has different provinces & health regions

```
    {
        "summary": [
            {
                "cases": 520,
                "cumulative_cases": 63244,
                "cumulative_deaths": 614.0,
                "date": "11-04-2021",
                "deaths": 0.0,
                "health_region": "Calgary",
                "province": "Alberta"
            },
            {
                "cases": 139,
                "cumulative_cases": 12660,
                "cumulative_deaths": 123.0,
                "date": "11-04-2021",
                "deaths": 0.0,
                "health_region": "Central",
                "province": "Alberta"
            } 
   ]
}
```

**Collection View Code **

//Firstly I'm trying to get a count for the rows. I'm not sure my approach is right or wrong

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            
            var count: Int = 0
            for text in 1...100{
                if jsonData?.summary[text].province == dataFromSelection {
                    count = jsonData?.summary.count ?? 0
                    print("count block")
                }
            }
            return count
        }
        
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            
            if collectionView == myCollectionView {
                    print("if block")
                if (dataFromSelection == jsonData?.summary[indexPath.row].province) {
                    print("im here")
                    let today = jsonData?.summary[indexPath.row].cases
                    let tDeaths = jsonData?.summary[indexPath.row].cumulative_deaths
                    let tCases = jsonData?.summary[indexPath.row].cumulative_cases
                    let regionName = jsonData?.summary[indexPath.row].health_region
                    
                    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "RegionCell", for: indexPath) as! RegionCell
                    cell.configure(region: regionName!, totCase: tCases!, todCases: today!, totDeaths: tDeaths!)
                    return cell
                }
```

[Image of simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FVNg.png)

**Please help me out on this**

- First I'm looking for the count of rows to be populated i.e jsonData.summary[index] == Alberta (say)
- second only those rows to appear who have Alberta as a province
  let me know what I'm doing wrong here. I'm fairly new to swift

Comment: If you use Codable and decode the json into an array of struct objects you will make things a lot easier for yourself.

Comment: can u plz be a little more specific. I'm using codable for Model [structure]. while decoding the data. i want to know like the URL I'm using give out data for all the provinces at once. it doesn't seem to give URL or province .that would've made things a lot easier

Comment: Sorry I misread your code. I would try to skip `jsonData?.` by directly assigning the `summary` to an array property

Comment: Does dataFromSelection come from another view controller or something? I mean is it something the user has selected?

Comment: yep the dataSelection comes from mainVC. i have used the filter on summary it works perfectly. thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create array for summary details and then Filter your summary array according to selection of province.
ex:

**let summaryArray = [
[
"cases": 520,
"cumulative_cases": 63244,
"cumulative_deaths": 614.0,
"date": "11-04-2021",
"deaths": 0.0,
"health_region": "Calgary",
"province": "Alberta"
],
[
"cases": 139,
"cumulative_cases": 12660,
"cumulative_deaths": 123.0,
"date": "11-04-2021",
"deaths": 0.0,
"health_region": "Central",
"province": "Alberta"
]
]**

**let filterArray = summaryArray.filter({($0["province"] as? String "") == dataFromSelection})**

And now use this **filterArray** for the count of rows and display the details in collection view cell